# Is it possible to create a dummy Rake::FileList?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake

I am working on some unit tests and I would like to create a populate `Rake::FileList` with some dummy files so I can check my code.

It currently seems like I have to create a FileList of a real directory on my system.

Thanks,

Parth

Comment: AFAIK, Rake::FileList is just a wrapper around Dir. You can use FakeFS gem to mock file system: https://github.com/defunkt/fakefs

Comment: Is it possible to just mock the `FileList` object?

Comment: I ended up just mocking out the `FileList` object for my tests